Why do coroutines need less memory than threads?
It is often said that coroutines could be thought of as "light threads" because they consume less memory. However, I wasn't able to find any explanation on why exactly that is the case. What do threads store that coroutines do not? Especially if we're talking about stackful coroutines which still need their own stack just like threads do.

One thing coroutines won't require is any assistance from the OS -- modern (non-green) threads require data structures to be set up in the kernel so that the OS's scheduler can know when to execute the thread's code.

What kind of data structures are needed to support threads? I would be content with some links since I wasn't able to find the information myself.

For example, Linux OS's scheduler has a process-table and each thread requires its own entry in that process-table.  You might find the question and answer here to be relevant (co-routines being similar in some respects to green/user-level threads):  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40877998/why-blocking-system-calls-blocks-entire-procedure-with-user-level-threads

@JeremyFriesner, Wow! Still true? (I stopped paying attention to Linux internals at least a decade ago. I remember back when they first added threads as a special kind of process that depended on some other process for its virtual memory, its file handles, sockets, and other resources. But, I always imagined that they eventually would refactor threads into first-class objects, entirely distinct from processes. Did my imagination fail me?)

@SolomonSlow AFAIK it's still true, but even if it had changed, the kernel still would need to know about the presence of each thread so that it can schedule it to run.  FWIW I think Linux's implementation is a reasonable one, since a process is really just a special-case of a thread (i.e. it's a thread that also has a memory-space allocated at the same time).  Maybe they should rename the table, though.

@JeremyFriesner, Suppose that somebody long ago invents a wheelbarrow. Then, somebody adds a second wheel to make a cart. Then, two more wheels make a wagon. Is each of those extra wheels really just a special-case of a wheelbarrow? A wheelbarrow minus the poles and the tub? Or, does it make sense to think of wheels as being a different kind of thing than the vehicle to which they are attached? IMO, regardless of the implementation, I think of threads as a different kind of thing than a process, even despite the fact that a process (vehicle) is no use without at least one thread (wheel.)

@SolomonSlow I'm not a Linux kernel developer, but if you think you know better than they do how the Linux kernel should be organized, you can subscribe to the Linux kernel developers' mailing list and tell them your ideas.

@SolomonSlow there are a bunch of established threading models, and making each thread a general purpose kernel-schedulable entity turns out to be the easiest to manage & reason about (and has the side-effect of keeping the scheduler simple too).

@Useless, I don't understand. The idea that "each thread [is] a general purpose...schedulable entity," seems to be compatible with how I prefer to describe the relationship between threads and processes, and it seems equally compatible with what Jeremy said about the actual workings of Linux. What distinguishes my abstraction from the Linux reality is that in my abstraction, each thread is nothing more than a general purpose, kernel-scheduleable entity. I.e., threads don't have VM. They don't have file handles or sockets or... Those all belong to the same process that owns the thread.

FWIW: I started thinking that way after I learned Java. In the Java model, the main thread of a program truly is indistinguishable from any other "non-daemon" thread. The main() routine can return, the thread that called it dies,* and all of the other threads just keep on doing whatever, as if nothing special happened. That's unlike most of the C language runtimes I have ever used in which returning from main() kills the process. [* "dies" in the sense, that there's nothing you can do from within the Java language to prove otherwise.]

Of course threads have sockets and VM. They're just the same sockets and VM as every other thread in the same process. The fact that main returning exits the process isn't a special feature of the first thread, but of the main function itself, because that's how returning from main is defined to work in both C and C++.

Java is different because its entry point is defined to work differently, not because its threads are any different.

@Useless, Re, "sockets and VM," Yup. Just like how each of my fingers has a heart and a liver and a brain. It's just the same heart and same liver and same brain that it shares with all of my other fingers. Re, main in C and C++ vs. main in Java, Yup. That looks like pretty much the same as what I said.


What kind of data structures are needed to support threads?

Here's an off-hand, incomplete list, pulled out of my... Uh,... memories of various different operating systems.
Per-thread data:
All of the following may be bundled into a single "Thread" object that lives in kernel space, and which could be a member of, or could be referenced by a slot in a global "thread table."

The thread's context. Whenever a thread is suspended, its context contains all of the values that must be loaded into hardware registers in order to resume running it.

The thread's state. Typically, the state either is running if it actually is running, or runnable if the only thing that prevents it from running is the lack of an available CPU, or it's blocked by something. If it's blocked, then the state probably contains a pointer to the descriptor for whatever queue (see below) eventually will unblock it. Depending on the OS, there may be other possible states such as, states that support debugging.

A reference to a "parent thread" or, to a "process," or both. In most desktop/server/mobile operating systems, every thread belongs to a process, and there will be places in the OS code where, having found a reference to a thread, it is necessary to find the process to which the thread belongs.

Other attributes: Threads may have "priorities," "base priorities," "nice values," "names," "processor affinities," ... whatever else meets the needs of the particular operating system.


Queues:
Whenever a thread is not running, then it must be waiting for something, and in the general case, there may be other threads awaiting the same thing. References to the waiting threads often are kept in queues, which also are kernel-space objects.

A global run queue contains references to all of the runnable threads in the system

Queues for blocked threads: A mutex will contain a queue of threads that are waiting to lock the mutex, Synchronization objects with other names, "mail slots," "semaphores," "events," "condition variables," etc. They all have queues of threads that are waiting for one reason or another.


The "queues" in most cases are more than just strict FIFO queues because (a) it often is necessary for high priority threads to be bumped to the head of a queue, and (b) it sometimes is necessary to remove a thread from the middle of a queue (e.g., if the process that owns it is peremptorily killed.)
Call Stack:
In virtually every operating system, a thread is expected to use the CPU's "call" and "return" instructions, if only when calling in to the operating system, but in most cases, also to support the programming language of the thread's code. Those call and return instructions implicitly use a dedicated call stack.
Unlike everything else mentioned above, the call stack is allocated in the owning process's virtual address space (a.k.a., in "user space.") Depending on the operating system, allocating the call stack for a new thread, and disposing of the call stack for a dead thread could either be the responsibility of the user-mode code that requested the new thread, or it could be done by kernel code.
Either way, the call stack probably is the single largest chunk of memory associated with the thread.
